# NOT HAVING (inverse HAVING) clause with aggregation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, cube, having-clause, oracle8i

I am trying to filter the results of a `GROUP BY CUBE` using the `HAVING` clause. However I need to keep rows that do not meet a combination of conditions.

I intuitively tried:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
NOT HAVING (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)
GROUP BY CUBE [...]
```

Sadly Oracle doesn't recognize `NOT HAVING` as valid syntax.

From a mathematical standpoint, inversing each individual condition does not yield the same result :

`HAVING (flag_1 != 1 AND flag_2 != 1 AND flag_3 != 1)`

How can I achieve the logical equivalent of `NOT HAVING` ?

Note: I found an existing question that was somewhat related, but it was specific to Microsoft Access and the goal was not the same, hence this new question­.

Comment: First is even `HAVING (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)` valid? Second from mathematical/SQL standpoint `col = 1` inversion is `col != 1 or col IS NULL` - three-valued logic

Comment: Try `HAVING NOT (flag_1=1...)`

Comment: Based on the ordering and single column reference, it doesn't seem like this is suited for `HAVING`. The `HAVING` clause is for filtering on some sort of aggregate expression. If all you want is to filter based on a column value, you need `WHERE NOT (flag_1 = 1 ...)`.

Comment: You're looking for `WHERE` instead of `NOT HAVING`. There is no reason for a `HAVING` or `NOT HAVING` for the condition you're testing. A SQL tutorial might be of use.

Comment: @KenWhite actually I am looking to filter post-aggregation, not pre-aggregation. Hence `HAVING` rather than `WHERE`.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda `HAVING (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)` is indeed valid syntax.

Comment: @kfinity I would think `HAVING NOT (flag_1=1...)` could work, I encourage you to post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical inverse of your HAVING clause requires that you change the AND's to OR's and, if columns are nullable, null-check as well.

EG (if nulls are possible):

```
HAVING (nvl(flag_1,1) != 1 OR NVL(flag_2,1) != 1 OR NVL(flag_3,1) != 1)
```

Comment: I just did this test : `HAVING flag_1 != 1`.
I am surprised that all rows for which `flag_1` is `NULL` are not retained.
As far as I know `NULL != 1`, so those rows should be there ?

Comment: @mach128x Any comparison with `NULL` is false.  `1 = NULL` is false; `1 != NULL` is also false.  This is explained in my answer.

Comment: In my specific application, `flag_1`, `flag_2` and `flag_3` are never `NULL`.
However because the clause would fail to provide the expected results if it was parsing any `NULL`'s, handling them properly is required in general outside of my own specific application. This answer and @MatthewMcPeak 's answer are both addressing this.
I finally selected to accept this answer, as I think the use of NVL is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution is to just change it to `HAVING NOT ...`

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]
HAVING NOT (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)
GROUP BY CUBE [...]
```

But I often find `NOT (...)` unintuitive; as an alternative, @MichaelBroughton's answer explains how to invert the logic from `NOT (x AND y)` to `NOT x OR NOT y`

Comment: This is the most elegant and simple solution IMHO. I don't know why I did not think of it earlier, putting `NOT` _after_ the `HAVING`, rather than _before_.  While I don't find `NOT` generally unintuitive, I guess it actually _is_ a bit unintuitive in that specific semantical context.
Still, elegance and no use of additional functions is a win in my book.

Comment: Elegant, but does not properly handle null values, unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as Michael Broughton's answer and I hate to duplicate but I thought it could be clearer.  If he wants to incorporate any of this into his answer, I'm happy to delete this one.

To determine the logical equivalent of NOT (boolean_expression), you can apply De Morgan's laws.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Basically, you reverse the logic of each term and change all ANDs to ORs and all ORs to ANDs.  So,

```
NOT (A AND B AND C) ==> (NOT A OR NOT B OR NOT C)
```

But you need to keep track of nulls too.  Here's the process:

Starting with...

```
HAVING NOT (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)
```

First, add the implicit assumptions about NULLs that exist in the starting expression.  E.g., if `flag_1=1`, then it is, of course, not NULL.

```
HAVING NOT (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_1 IS NOT NULL 
        AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_2 IS NOT NULL 
        AND flag_3 = 1 AND flag_3 IS NOT NULL)
```

Now, apply the first part of De Morgan's laws and reverse the logic of each term.  So, e,g., `flag_1 = 1` becomes `flag_1 != 1`...

```
HAVING (flag_1 != 1 AND flag_1 IS NULL 
    AND flag_2 != 1 AND flag_2 IS NULL 
    AND flag_3 != 1 AND flag_3 IS NULL)
```

Finally, apply the second part of De Morgan's laws and switch all ANDs->ORs and vice versa...

```
HAVING (flag_1 != 1 OR flag_1 IS NULL 
     OR flag_2 != 1 OR flag_2 IS NULL 
     OR flag_3 != 1 OR flag_3 IS NULL)
```

And there is your answer.

#### How about just `NOT (flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1)`?

This does not work because it does not handle null values as one would expect.  In Oracle, any comparison with null is false.  So,

```
    (1 = NULL) ... false
NOT (1 = NULL) ... also false
```

So a row with `flag_1` and `flag_2` both equal to 1 but `flag_3` null would NOT show up in your results.

Comment: In my specific application, `flag_1`, `flag_2` and `flag_3` are never `NULL`.
However because the clause would fail to provide the expected results if it was parsing any `NULL`'s, handling them properly is required in general outside of my own specific application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought about adapting a similar method based on `CASE` that I sometimes use inside a `WHERE`.
It seems that `CASE` works inside `HAVING` as well !

Solution:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM [...]

HAVING
    CASE
        WHEN flag_1 = 1 AND flag_2 = 1 AND flag_3 = 1
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END = 1

GROUP BY CUBE [...]
```

Comment: Using that specific logic with `HAVING` would fail to provide the expected results if it was parsing any NULL's. See @Michael Brougton's and @Matthew McPeak's answers for more robust solutions.
This solution is still valid if there are no `NULL` flags to parse.